# LyX does not recognize pre-existing natbib.sty file and article.cls

Tags: lyx

Although via MiKTeX console, I am able to see that `natbib.sty` is installed on my machine, on opening a `.lyx` document, LyX complains that it is not installed:

[image]

Furthermore, I obtain a new error that I did not obtain before in terms of missing external components related to `article.cls`:

[image]

On clicking through these warnings, the article does compile and typeset properly within LyX.

Is there a way to fix these within LyX?

---

ETA: On looking at some other questions, it appears that I had to do `Tools -> Reconfigure`. This seems to run for a while (took about 10 minutes on my machine) and then, once you close and restart, the warnings do not appear.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Danke Schon! I have used LyX and PCTeX for many years now, so I am bit flummoxed at the above warnings.